# How to verify fingerprints using hashcode , hashcode of fingerprints is also saved in database as binary data

Tags: c#, hashcode

I am trying to verify fingerprints by converting them to hashcode

```
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(ImageToByteArray(_mainFinger.Image)));
                byte[] f_hash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(ImageToByteArray(_mainFinger.Image))));



public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        //using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        //{
        Image img = new Bitmap(imageIn);
        MemoryStream msi = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(msi, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        return msi.ToArray();
    }
```

I save the fingerprint and its hash in database and to verify, I am using the hashcode of fingerprint to match that with dataabse value but I cant get to to work

Comment: Fingerprint matching is a heck of a lot more complicated than just comparing a hash of two images of the fingerprints. Far out of scope for a stack overflow question.

Comment: also: storing actual images of fingerprints sounds like a terrible idea for infosec (caveat: I'm not a biometrics expert, but HTC got into trouble for this: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/aug/10/htc-fingerprints-world-readable-unencrypted-folder)

Comment: I was struggling when I started working on it and someone here on stackoverflow suggested to use hash code for verification.

Comment: Your approach can’t work as the kind of hash you choose that two pictures must be absolutely identical down to every pixel’s exact color and brightness, which is just impossible. For image matching you would a perceptual hash, which is also invariant to rotation, scale and translation. However, for fingerprint images you would usually first transform your image to its minutiaes, extract important features/points of interest (like crossings of minutiae, where they bifurcate or join, and so on), then again transform them to be invariant and compare these features.